# Communicating with a Rest API through PHP - how to process?

Tags: php, rest, api, curl, stormpath

I have been trying to use the Stormpath API in my website. I cannot work out how to communicate with the API through PHP. I've tried some variations of cURL but I think I'm missing something...At this stage I'm just trying to make the request from a blank page with known account details - I'm not getting any result.

The API documentation provides this example, for example. What is the simplest way for me to submit the request this using PHP?

**Request**

```
POST /oauth/token HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: smooth-ensign.apps.stormpath.io

grant_type=password&username=jakub%40stormpath.com&password=Password1%21
```

**Response**

```
{
  "access_token": "eyJraWQi[...]0dTpiM",
  "refresh_token": "eyJraWQi[...]okvVI",
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "expires_in": 3600
}
```

I also have the Stormpath PHP SDK installed, if that provides a better way to do this.

Comment: once you authorise and get that token, you use it in future requests. note it expires so after the 3600 secounds you need to do that step again

Comment: you should use the SDK: https://docs.stormpath.com/php/product-guide/latest/quickstart.html#installing-the-sdk

Comment: @nogad - I have used the SDK. If you look at the section on [generating-an-oauth-2-0-access-token](https://docs.stormpath.com/php/product-guide/latest/auth_n.html#generating-an-oauth-2-0-access-token) you will see that it refers to the API for token generation. I can't for the life of me work out how to generate a token using the information they have provided (see above).

Comment: the above responce contains the access token